# Pyspark pandas udf Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 4531, got 4530.'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have an SKlearn LOF Model that I want to implement as a pandas UDF to use on a PySpark DF that has one column ("features") That is an array with 4530 rows and 24 features, each of type double.
First, I create the function:

```
def calculate_lof(pandas_df):
    lof = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=20, contamination=0.1) 
    X = np.array(pandas_df.tolist()).reshape(-1,1)
    results = lof.fit_predict(X)
    return pd.DataFrame({'outlier_score': results})
```

Then I define the pandas UDF:

```
@pandas_udf("double")
def lof_udf(pandas_df: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
  pandas_df["outlier"] = pandas_df.apply(calculate_lof)
  return pandas_df["outlier"]
```

And then i call the function:

```
# Apply the Pandas UDF to the 'features' column in the Spark DataFrame
result_df = lof_df.withColumn('outlier_score', lof_udf(lof_df["features"]))
```

The error I get is the following:

```
PythonException: 'pyspark.errors.exceptions.base.PySparkRuntimeError: [SCHEMA_MISMATCH_FOR_PANDAS_UDF] Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 4531, got 4530.'. Full traceback below:
```

I already tried many different types like `np.array()` or lists

Comment: Are you including Headers in your count of lines?

Comment: @user238607 when i use .count() on the spark dataframe, i get 4530. That should not include the header.

Comment: I would suggest to limit your dataframe to just 2-10 rows and check if you get the same off by 1 error. If you do, it means, there is issue in your pipeline and not the data.